# OpenGL camera is laggy

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I was setting up a camera following [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Glescraft_4). My problem is that when I move it isn't fluid, it kinda jumps. I'm calculating the MVP whenever the mouse moves using this code:

```
void motion(int x, int y) {
    static bool wrap = false;

    if(!wrap) {
        int ww = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        int wh = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        int dx = x - ww / 2;
        int dy = y - wh / 2;

        const float mousespeed = 0.001;

        angles.x += dx * mousespeed;
        angles.y += dy * mousespeed;


        if(angles.x < -M_PI)
            angles.x += M_PI * 2;
        else if(angles.x > M_PI)
            angles.x -= M_PI * 2;

        if(angles.y < -M_PI / 2)
            angles.y = -M_PI / 2;
        if(angles.y > M_PI / 2)
            angles.y = M_PI / 2;

        lookat.x = sinf(angles.x) * cosf(angles.y);
        lookat.y = sinf(angles.y);
        lookat.z = cosf(angles.x) * cosf(angles.y);
        view = glm::lookAt(position, position + lookat, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

        // move mouse pointer back to the center of the window
        wrap = true;
        glutWarpPointer(ww / 2, wh / 2);
    } else {
        wrap = false;
    }
}
```

And then I'm updating the attribute on my 'OnIdele()' function:

```
void onIdle() {
    glUseProgram(program);

    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * view * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

My question is, is this the right way to implement this? Is there any way to avoid the laggyness?

Also if you don't mind me asking, how exactly does this code work? I know it limits where you can look but I can't seem to make sense of it:

```
 if(angles.x < -M_PI)
            angles.x += M_PI * 2;
        else if(angles.x > M_PI)
            angles.x -= M_PI * 2;

        if(angles.y < -M_PI / 2)
            angles.y = -M_PI / 2;
        if(angles.y > M_PI / 2)
            angles.y = M_PI / 2;
```

Comment: Can you try to describe a little more what 'laggy' means in your case? I know its hard to describe a visual effect sometimes but its hard for me to imagine exactly what you could be seeing.  Also when does `onIdle()` get called? Is it executed every frame on a regular basis?

Comment: By laggy I mean when I move the mouse there is a clear 'jump' as your view point changes and not a smooth transition. And for `onIdle` I set it as `glutIdleFunc(onIdle);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if increasing `mousespeed` makes a difference. After you find the distance the mouse has moved, stored in `dx` and `dy`, you scale the distance by `mousespeed` before adding it to the camera's angles. The lower the value of `mousespeed` the less your mouse movement will affect the angles of your camera, and vice versa.

Also the code you asked about is limiting your camera angles to between 0 and PI * 2, or 0 and 360 degrees.

Comment: Hm I decreased it by a power of ten but it still is 'jumping' it's just doing it at smaller angles.

Comment: Based on your comment it looks like you need angular velocities associated with your camera. Use the distance moved by the mouse to set the camera's angular velocity so that the camera rotates based on time elapsed between update cycles.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial that may be useful to you - [OpenGL Camera](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/camera2.html). The `mouseMovement` and `camera` functions are what you need here.